# Converting degrees to other units of measurement

Tags: mysql, coordinates, distance

I am storing a point as latitude and longitude in a Mysql server. They are both `float(10,6)`. Given a radius, say 100 yards or 100 meters, how can I calculate points around the center. I was thinking of using GIS but I heard it is incomplete or very limited in functionality.

Comment: This is simply a poor question. MySQL is totally irrelevant. Are you talking about Lat/Lon on the planet Earth? The radius of the planet/body and the distance from the center of that body will determine how degrees equate to any other measurement.

Comment: @desmusxvii: you are absolutely right on that. I spent some time in Google and I managed to find this: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/61135.html
Therefore all I have to do is write the equations in sql format.

Answer (score 0):

1) Tranform the lat/lon to a cartesian based coordinate system of units meter,
the tranformed point is now at (x,y)
2) Use school mathemathics (polar coordinates) to calculate the points:

2a) create points on circle at (0,0)  with polar coordinates (r* sin (phi), r* cos(phi)), r in meters, phi in radians
   2b) add (x,y) to all that resulting points, to move the circle points from center (0,0) to (x,y)
3) tranform all points back to lat/lon